# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{(ax+1)^{-ax}-(bx+1)^{-bx}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

> Calculate the integral:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{(ax+1)^{-ax}-(bx+1)^{-bx}}{x}dx$$

Frullani integrals.

I do not understand how I should think about this problem. I expect a response or an idea.

Comment: Let $f(x)=(x+1)^{-x}$...

Comment: I want to calculate this integral

Comment: see here https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullanische_Integrale

Comment: I do not understand how to calculate after this theorem just writes f(0)lnb/a

Comment: which would be the function where I should calculate f(0)

Comment: I do not know how to solve this exercise, I'm a student, and I did not make this kind of calcul made the genre of this integral

Comment: Choose $f(x) = (x+1)^{-x}$ and notice that Frullani's integral gives $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(ax+1)^{-ax}-(bx+1)^{-bx}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = (f(0) - f(\infty))\log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right). $$ Now notice that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\infty) = 0$.

Comment: log(b/a) ? results final